# How can i do search inside same page in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can i do search inside same page in MVC Razor? For example; my page do not any result when open if i search return.i must use `IEnumerable<model>` for getting result but if i use `IEnumerable<model>` for empty page, i am getting error.

**Search page**

```
@model IEnumerable<SearchResult>
<span>Search results:</span>
<p>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
       @item.Title<br/>
    }
</p>
```

Comment: What error do you get? and how do you send data from controller to View? Can you show this code too?

Comment: I am getting error when open page first, because i am calling page as Get method and this page's ActionResult return only View(), do not return any model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return empty model for such case. for example in controller code:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    // some actions
    return View(new List<SearchResult>());
}
```

in that case it will send empty model, and won't fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model that contain the search properties and the result list.

**Model**

```
Public class MySearchModel{
public string searchInput { get; set; }
public List<mySearchResultModel> resultList { get; set; }}
```

**Controller**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MySearchModel(); 
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MySearchModel model)
    {

        model.searchInput //filter
            model.mySearchResultModel = //query where filter
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model MySearchModel

<div>
 @Html.LabelFor(x => x.searchInput)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.searchInput)
</div>

<span>Search results:</span>
 @foreach (var item in Model.mySearchResultModel){
    @item.Title<br />
}
```

Another way to accomplish the same is to add your search inputs and map them to the controller action that you are posting using the input name:

**Controller**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {


        var model = new mySearchResultModel();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(mySearchResultModel model, string searchInput)
    {


            model.mySearchResultModel = //query where filter (searchInput)
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<mySearchResultModel>
<input type="text" name="searchInput"/>

Search results:
@foreach(var item in Model) { @item.Title<br/> }
```